# Updated php7.so files for Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, centos, apache2.4

I'm trying to upgrade to PHP7 on Apache 2.4 with Centos 6.7

First, I used yum to install php70w which installs PHP7 with Apache 2.2.

Then I upgraded to Apache 2.4 using yum. This was successful.

I then copied the php7.so files to the Apache 2.4 modules directory and then configured the httpd.conf file to include them.

When I restart httpd24 it produces the following error:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-php.conf: 
Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so:
undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

I've learned that this is because Apache has changed the name of there API [see here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/developer/new_api_2_4.html/).  So the php.so files are trying to call the API through the old name.

Is there a way to edit the php.so files?  Or is there a location to download updated files?
Or is there a different way I should be going about this update?

Answer (score 0):

You need mod_php specifically built against Apache 2.4.  No Apache module works w/o being at least recompiled against 2.2 and 2.4 by design.

Might be wise to take this opportunity to bail on mod_php and configure PHP via fastcgi.  The world has really moved on from mod_php.